# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer in SharePoint 2013 OOTB list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, ootb

I am getting following error in SharePoint 2013 when I try to access `DispForm.aspx` of a custom list.

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer
```

I found two solutions but problem is I am unable to find the setting they are talking about.

**Solution 1**
Changing the Webpart setting `CSR Render Mode` to `Server Render`.
From where do I find this setting? I am unable to open the DispForm.aspx page in browser so how I can open webpart setting?

**Solution 2**
Add `UseLegacyForm="TRUE"` attribute in `<Form` tag of `DispForm.aspx`.
I opened DispForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer but there is no such thing as `<Form` so where do I change this setting?

Answer (score 1):

**For Solution 1**:
List->Form Web Parts (in the ribbon) - > Default Display Form -> then Edit Web Part
Under the Miscellaneous category, you would see **CSR render Mode**

[image]
[image]

For more information see [here](https://sharepoint-thoughts.com/2017/08/client-side-rendering-in-forms-in-depth/)

**For Solution 2**

[**form**] element is in the **Maser Page**

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
```

Comment: When trying solution 1, I am getting same error when I click on `Default Display Form` in `Form Web Parts` in ribbon.    

For solution 2 I am not sure if this is the right form. Because if you take a look at the solution provided here `https://www.keapoint.com/workaround-the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property-in-sharepoint-2013-list-forms/` the form element is different.

Comment: Your Display Form might have got corrupted if you had opened it in the Designer, and for some reason it got updated. It's not recommended to make changes to the original forms, but make a copy of it and then make changes.